# Cleaning up the AS3 Code

Tags: actionscript-3, code-cleanup

Will someone help me clean up this as3 code i have been working on this for hours on end. It supposed to be a flamethrower. If you can't do it or don't want to do it than can someone give me a link to a website that is almost exactly like this meaning with the mouse movement thing and stuff.

here is the website http://wonderfl.net/c/6sUl

Comment: This is a Q/A type of website where you ask for help with specific issues you are unable to overcome. Not a "do it for me please" forum.

Comment: And by the way the code works fine. Are you trying to jack someone else's work but don't understand it?

Comment: I am very new to actionscript so i really dont understand all of it.

Comment: Okay well check out this link http://gotoandlearn.com/. You can learn a lot here, but posting questions like this is not the way to learn and just junks up this website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not going to rewrite the code for you. However I will tell you what you need to learn to being able to develop your own flamethrower. This is what you need:

- How to capture the position of the mouse: http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flashcs3/detecting_direction_mouse_movement.htm
- How to determine the angle from the starting position to where the mouse is positioned: http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/154/1/Mouse-Angle-Detection-II/Page1.html
- How to create a simple particle engine that will produce the flames: http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/607/1/A-simple-particle-system-using-Actionscript-3/Page1.html
- How to figure out the dynamics of how the flames changes from flames to smoke and the changing of sizes depending on the angle and movement speed of the mouse.

A good starting point:

Build a very simple flamethrower which just generates red dots which moves towards where the mouse is positioned. Then beging to experiment with making the animation a bit uneven when it comes to where it ends so that you get a bigger spread of particles. Then start to experiment with different sprites instead of red dots.